# How does mounted combat work?

Tags: dnd-5e, mounted-combat

I couldn't find a direct explanation for these questions in the PHB:

1. Is it possible to wield two-handed weapons, a shield or dual wield whilst mounted?
2. Is it possible for a rogue to dash in, attack, then use a cunning action to disengage while mounted?
3. Does your mount become the target of an enemy attack against you while you are mounted?
4. Is it possible for a monster to choose whether to attack the PC or the mount in combat?

Comment: Related: [How many hands do you use to control a mount?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97207/how-many-hands-do-you-use-to-control-a-mount)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. You can do these while not mounted, and the mounted rules don't forbid any of these, so yes, this is possible.
2. While the rogue can take the disengage action, it has no effect. The mount uses its own movement, not yours, and therefore provokes opportunity attacks on its own. While you're on the mount, you do not provoke opportunity attacks since you're not using your movement to leave the reach of your enemies. However, the mount does provoke opportunity attacks, and enemies can choose whether to target you or the mount with the opportunity attack. The mount itself can still use its action to disengage, though.
3. It can. You and the mount are two separate creatures, so attacks can target either of you. Spells with area-of-effect affect both you and the mount.
4. Absolutely. Since you're two separate creatures, there's nothing stopping a monster from attacking you or the mount, and the creature can even choose who to attack when the mount provokes an attack of opportunity.

Comment: xan: for answer 2, it seems that the rogue would need to dismount to disengage via cunning action.  If that's how you see it, that might be worth folding into the answer.  Or not.

Comment: He could dismount then disengage, but he doesn't really gain much from this anyway. The mount is still in melee range of the enemies, and would have to disengage anyway. In fact, if he dismounts to outside the range of enemies without disengaging, he would provoke attacks of opportunity, since he's using his movement to move outside their reach. Cunning Action is practically useless for a mounted rogue, since neither disengage nor dash transfer to the mount, and hide is very limited in usability while mounted.

Comment: So, from what I understood, your mount simply grants you more movement and it can be targeted instead of you. But when you say the mount can use it's action to disengage, you are infering that the mount can use both its move and its action allowing the mounted character to make it's own action and bonus action on the same turn? Also, Does the PC gain any kind of advantage (to AC or something else) for technically being in higher ground, or partially covered? Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @Seyres If the answer to your question suggests other questions to you, correct etiquette for the site is to ask those as a new question putting in a hyperlink to this question.

Comment: The really short answer to your first question is yes. Also, the mounted character can use half his move to dismount after the mount has spent its move. The really short answer to the second question is no, being mounted gives no bonuses/advantage to AC or attacks.