# How many hands do you use to control a mount?

Tags: dnd-5e, mounted-combat

When riding a horse and fighting with a longsword, can you use a longsword with two hands or do you have to use a longsword with one hand because you have to control the horse with the other? And does this rule have an exception?

Comment: Only Exception I cna think of is how you can treat Lance as a 1-handed weapon while riding, but this is mostly so you can use a shield in the other.

Comment: Suggest that, the next time you go on vacation, you ride a horse.  Knees and feet are also involved in horsemanship.  (Plus, horses are cool animals).

Comment: Does the lack of stirrups change this?

Comment: Earlier versions of DnD had the "Ride" skill, its "guide with knees" use case was exactly for the situation you are asking about. In 5e Ride was merged into Handle Animal, its uses are mostly on DM's discretion. If your DM focuses on mounted combat, they might use additional checks.

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker Interesting question about stirrups. I'm not sure how important they are, given that most of the civilisations of antiquity, up to and including the Romans, did not use stirrups. Then again, there is the Great Stirrup Controversy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Stirrup_Controversy). Sorry if I'm teaching granny to suck eggs.

Answer (score 14):

## None

No rule in the [Mounted Combat](https://5thsrd.org/combat/mounted_combat/) rules requires that you use a hand to control a mount. Mounts could likely then be controlled by commands or through other bodily cues, such as a light kick.

Comment: fwiw: most mounted knights had shields (and implicitly a weapon in the other hand) and so hand no free hands. Same for Mongol mounted archers, mounted riflemen, etc.

Comment: This answer will surprise exactly 0 people who have ever ridden a horse.

Comment: @DerekStucki Granted, it is more complicated in a fantasy setting, where mounts can include giant lizards, wolves, giant eagles, and more.

Comment: @DerekStucki I've ridden a horse a couple of times and it surprises me. While I believe that  a very good horseman with a very well trained horse could be able to fully guide the horse with their knees/legs/body, it seems as though your average rider tends to use reins and a bridle. Even with mounted knights who used a shield they would usually be seen holding the reins in their shield hand https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/81/9a/1b/819a1b00ee1803779d308f27ffc6f751.jpg . My guess would be that guiding your mount purely through body cues would bring a penalty to riding check.

Comment: @DRF what ride check? 5e has no such thing. A quick Google search shows that reinless riding is considered an intermediate skill for a rider, and a basic skill for the horse. Reins are a (very substantial) convenience only.

Comment: @DerekStucki - A DM could reasonably call for an animal handling or vehicles (land) check when navigating a mount through a narrow pass, up a steep slope, or through some other dangerous terrain.

Comment: @THiebert absolutely, but there is no "ride check" for basic circumstances, as opposed to 3.5e, where the term comes from.